# Cannot add Youtube iframe tag

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMce and I want to add another button with 'Youtube add' functionality. The problem is with adding the iframe using 'mceInsertContent':

```
h = '<iframe class="video" src="' + f.width.value + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, h);
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it? It doesn't want to render either in the editor or on the final page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, `iframe` is not a valid tag that can be submitted through TinyMCE. You can, however, extend your current list of valid elements to include this tag if you are sure it will not be abused.

See the [`extended_valid_elements`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements) property during your call to `init()`.